# Android ViewPropertyAnimator and ValueAnimator: How can I do fast-forward?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using ViewPropertyAnimator like this:

```
view.animate().alpha(to).setDuration(duration);
```

And ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, width);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        viewGroup.setMinimumWidth((Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
anim.setDuration(duration).start();
```

Sometimes I want to cancel the animation before its finished, *but still apply the remaining steps immediately* (as if the animation had completed). Is there a simple way to accomplish this using the APIs, or do I need to wrap the Animators in another class and handle this myself?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of stopping a running animation.

```
Animator.end()     // end the animation
Animator.cancel()  // cancel the animation
```

You can use either the `end()` method or the `cancel()` method. In both cases the animation will stop and can only be restarted by calling `start()`.
The difference between `end()` and `cancel()` is the state that the animated objects will be in after the call to the method.
When calling `cancel()` the animation will stop in its tracks, leaving the animated objects in an intermediate state.

**When calling the end() method the animation will effectively be fast forwarded into the final state of the animation.**

All objects will appear the way they would at the end of the animation.

Source: http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1482

Comment: This works for ValueAnimator, but for ViewPropertyAnimator I probably need to handle it in the listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AnimatorListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) for this.

```
anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        // Set view properties here as if the animation had completed
        viewGroup.setMinimumWidth(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
});
```

Comment: This would work, except for "By" animations like translationYBy(). Then I will need to know how far the animation went when it was cancelled. On the other hand, maybe it works to just do animation.end() in the onAnimationCancel callback... I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind using a third party library then [android-transition](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition) can be used:

**Import the library in Gradle:**
compile 'com.github.kaichunlin.transition:core:0.9.2'

Your ViewPropertyAnimator scenario would become

```
TransitionAnimation animation = 
    ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(view).alpha(to).duration(duration).buildAnimation();
```

Your ValueAnimator scenario would become

```
final int width = <width>;
TransitionAnimation animation = 
    ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(viewGroup).duration(duration).addTransitionHandler(new TransitionHandler() {
       @Override
       public void onUpdateProgress(TransitionController controller, View target, float progress) {
           target.setMinimumWidth((int) (progress*width));
       }
   }).buildAnimation();
```

Then call `animation.startAnimation();` to start and `animation.endAnimation();` to end the animation and applying the final state.

The advantage of this library is that that a single concept/class can be used where it would require a mix of different classes (i.e. ViewPropertyAnimator & ValueAnimator), and that the animation state/progress can be tied to UI state like how much the Drawer is being pulled out.